# Save array in one field of database or save each value in separated field?

Tags: php, mysql, database, message

I work on a message system. in this message system admin can send messages to single user, user group or all users and users just can see messages.
know i want to find unread messages in user panel.
i designed two database table like this :
1- msg_messages :

`| id | title | messages | date | status |`

2- msg_control :
`| id | message_id | from | toUser | toGroup | status |`

Know i think about this two methods of saving users who saw the messages.
Method 1 : create a string with readers id Like this : `1,5,9,12,...` and check users id with this string by `Strpos` php function or `in_array` function.

Method 2 : create a new table like below table and save readers id in that :
`| id | message_id | readers_id | date |`

which one of this two method is better ?

---

### A new way to find unread messages ...

after think more about this problem i decided to use a new method by combining  method 1 and method 2. actually i added a new column to `user` table and named it `read_msg` . system will save read `message_id` in this filed in a string like this `1,5,9,12,98,125,...` for each user (`message_id` in this filed refer to `msg_control` table ) and when we want to find unread messages just need to compare `msg_control` ids with this filed. 
 
we use `strpos` to compare `read_msg` and `message_id` because its faster than `is_array` ([reference](http://dev.airve.com/demo/speed_tests/php/strpos_vs_inarray_vs_array_search.php)).

Comment: Either is fine it will be more performance based as your tables get larger but instead of using `strpos` or `in_array` in php you may want to use MySQLs `NOT FIND_IN_SET(1, readers)` if you are using a a set to find unread messages.

Answer (score 1):

I once implemented a small messaging system and structured it as follows (however it might not be perfect and there are multiple possibilities):

Tab Conversation

```
ID | Conv Title | ... master data
```

Participants

```
UserId | ConversationID | lastRead
```

MessageHeaders

```
ConversationID | messageID | ... use your "inbox"-schema here. You can remove the toUser/toGroup etc. fields as this is covered using the participants table.
```

Using the timestamps of a message and the "last-read"-timestamp of a user for a conversation you can determine which messages are new/unread and which are not.
Using constructs like in your first suggestion can become very inefficient. Storing data atomar is considered good practice in my opinion. This means no multiple values in a single field.